# htaccess rewrite not working for multiple files in main directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

The title does not fully describe the issue, but I have rewrite rules setup to go to three different files which exist in the main directory: api.php, admin.php, and index.php

**Here is my .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 ^(api)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 ^(admin)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin\.php|api\.php|admin|api|_|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

For /admin and /api I get a 500 Internal Server Error.  I am not sure why that happens, yet if I put those php files within a folder like /_ and edit the .htaccess to match it then it rewrites without an error. Am I limited on the number of main directory file redirects I can do? Or did I am I missing something?

**My main goal is:**

Redirect all /api requests to /api.php/whatever/is/after/here

Redirect all /admin requests to /admin.php/whatever/is/after/here

Redirect all other requests apart from the exceptions to /index.php/whatever/is/here

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(api.*)$ /api.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(admin.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin\.php|api\.php|admin|api|_|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that works. Any chance you know why?  I find that quite odd that I have to either put my files within folders or check for already existing files otherwise it won't redirect.  I really didn't want it to go to files/directories even if they do exist. I want it to rewrite everything.

Comment: For my piece of mind I didn't really want to open up all those files and directories.  I tried adding RewriteCond $1 ^(api|admin) to the first rule but then I had the same problem as before where admin and api were giving 500 errors and everything else worked fine.  I kinda wanted to be strict that unless someone is coming from api or admin (and the few exceptions) they will be rewritten to index.php regardless of file or directory existence.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I simply had to be more specific in my regex match. Previously I was matching anything that started with "admin" or "api" (eg. admins-at-the-new-school) which actually I was unaware of and would cause problems in the future anyways.  I changed my regex and now it only matches if it's the end of a line, a pound sign, slash, or question mark. (based on testing)

**Here is my final code:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(api(?=$|[/?#]).*)$ /api.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(admin(?=$|[/?#]).*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin\.php|api\.php|_|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I appreciate Croises answer, and it did help give me an idea of what might be going wrong that his solution would work.  However, this is what I was looking for as I did not want to open up access to files and directories simply because they existed.